# C++ converting between unsigned integers and signed integers

Tags: c++

Why does the following piece of code write B2 first and A1 then? Shouldn't it write both A1? Implicit datatype in C++ converts from signed int to unsigned int (higher in hierarchy)

```
short a=-5;
unsigned short b=-5u;
if(a==b)
    printf("A1");
else
    printf("B2");
// prints B2

int a2=-5;
unsigned int b2=-5u;
if(a2==b2)
    printf("A1");
else
    printf("B2");
return 0;

// prints A1
```

Comment: Shorts are promoted to ints.

Comment: I changed "casting" to "converting" in the title. There are no casts in this code; the question is about conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting negative signed integral type into `unsigned` always underflows and it yields modulo arithmetic. `unsigned int x = (unsigned int)-1` stores `UINT_MAX` into `x`.

[Example](http://ideone.com/xYSUKj):

```
unsigned int x = (unsigned int) -1;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
x = (unsigned int) -5;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

outputs:

```
4294967295
4294967291
```

Note that both `-1` and `-5` have been converted into extremely high values, whose difference is equal to 4 as well.

Answer (score 1):

for the given code

```
short a=-5;
unsigned short b=-5u;
if(a==b)
    printf("A1");
else
    printf("B2");
```

for an implementation where `sizeof(short)` < `sizeof(int)`, when `a` is promoted to `int` you get the `-5` value preserved, and when `b` is promoted to `int` you get the 2<sup>k</sup> - 5 value preserved, where k is the number of value representation bits in an `unsigned short`.

so, as `int` they're different, even though they may be the same `short` size bitpatterns.